# How to prove $b \ll a (a^{2}b^2)^{2.1/k} $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

In the paper [linear forms in the logarithms of real algebraic numbers close to 1](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/ConfMumbaidef.pdf), it is

written on page $9$ that

> It follows from (13) and Lemma 2 with $\eta=0.1 $ we have that,
>   $$b \ll a (a^{2}b^2)^{2.1/k} $$

**The image of page 9 :**

[image]

How do we prove $b \ll a (a^{2}b^2)^{2.1/k} $?

**My Confusion :** Note, if $k$ increases then ${2.1/k}$ goes close to $0$, so it is confusing

how the inequality holds true.

Comment: I'd swear I read this exact same question yesterday or the day before. Did you delete that one and post this one instead, in hopes that someone would answer this time?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes,  its not a duplicate question

Comment: But it's still a **waste of the time of people who take the time to read and respond to questions** -- we look at this one and think "Is that different? Should I take the time to check?" That's just rude. Nonetheless, I'm going to make a useful suggestion: email the author of the paper. He'll probably be thrilled that someone actually cares enough to check the details, and will be happy to try to explain them to you.

Comment: @JohnHughes the author is a top class mathematician, they don't read email... they don't get thrilled ... anyway, I didn't know  that posting same question is  considered rude despite deletion of previous copy... thanks for informing ...

Comment: A bunch of my close friends are 'top-class mathematicians' (my PhD is in mathematics). They *do* read email, and they *are* generally pleased when someone cares about what they're doing. Have you *tried* emailing and gotten no response? Or are you just assuming this?

Comment: @JohnHughes , never mailed a mathematician, but failed to get reply from academics  from Computer Science ... also  these are trivial for math students( I am from CS).. why should a math-professor reply?? anyway I will consider ur advice , Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial solution to what I think is your problem (namely, that you're having a tough time working through this paper), although not to the immediate question you asked; I'm suggesting that you consider writing to the author saying something like this:

> Hello.
>
> I'm a computer science student, and I've been trying to work my way through your paper, "Linear Forms in the Logarithms of ...". As you can see by the questions I've been asking on Math Stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/257587/mike-sq), my mathematical background is not all that sophisticated, so some of the steps that you assumed readers could fill in are well beyond my filling-in skills. I'd appreciate it if you could help me in a few places.
>
> I apologize for writing in English; I do not speak French well enough to write coherent questions about math in French.
>
> Right now I'm stuck on the remark following Lemma 2 on page 9. You write ...

It's hard for me to imagine that you'd get no response at all to such a note, even if the response is something like "I think, judging by some of your earlier questions, that perhaps that this paper is a bit too advanced for your current level of mathematical understanding and sophistication. Perhaps you should complete at least the junior-level courses for mathematics majors at your university before trying to read it, or you'll have troubles with almost every sentence." The author, after all, is probably very well suited to judge what preparation is needed to read his paper.

What I anticipate is that the author will say something like "This statement holds under the hypotheses written above; perhaps I should have been clearer, but $a$ must be at least ..., and $k$ is no greater than ..., hence ..."

Comment: I will try :) ...  thanks for ur answer sir.

Comment: Update: I mailed the author  asking two questions... no reply... one of the question is -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913968/proof-explanation-varlambda-ll-alpha-eta-rd

Answer (score 2):

We know,
$ \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \left(\frac{xz}{y^2}\right)^k\right|\leq \frac{1}{b} \cdots (13)$

Here, $xz= ((a+1)(ab^2+1))^\frac{1}{k}, y^2= (ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}.$

So, $ \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab+1)^2} \right|\leq \frac{1}{b} \cdots (a)$

Since, $(ab+1)>ab\implies(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}>(ab)^\frac{2}{k}$

$\implies \frac{1}{(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}}<\frac{1}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} \implies \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}}<\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}}$

$\implies -\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}}> -\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}}$ [since, the inequality sign

changes when both sides are multiplied  by $-1$.]

$\implies-\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} < -\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}}$ [changing sides]

$\implies (\frac{a+1}{a}) -\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} < (\frac{a+1}{a}) -\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}}$

$\implies \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} \right|  \leq \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab+1)^\frac{2}{k}} \right|$

Using inequality (a), we deduce-

$\left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} \right|  \leq \frac{1}{b} \cdots (b)$

***By inspection***, we see-   $ \left|(\frac{a+1}{a})^\frac{1}{k} \right |\leq \left|\frac{a+1}{a} \right | $

$\implies  \left|(\frac{a+1}{a})^\frac{1}{k}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}}\right |\leq \left|\frac{a+1}{a}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} \right | $

[subtracting $\frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}}$ on both sides]

Using inequality (b), we deduce-

$\left|(\frac{a+1}{a})^\frac{1}{k}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}}\right |\leq \frac{1}{b}\ \cdots (c) $

To use **Lemma 2**, we need to re-parameterize $p, q$ of  **Lemma 2**

according to inequality $(13)$, so
let,  $p= (xz)^k, q= (ab)^\frac{2}{k} $, then-

$ \left|(1+\frac{1}{a})^\frac{1}{k}- \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\right| > \frac{c_5}{aq^{\epsilon +2 }} $  [ **Lemma 2**]

$\implies \left|(1+ \frac{1}{a})^\frac{1}{k}- \frac{(xz)^k}{(ab)^\frac{2}{k}} \right| > \frac{c_5}{a(ab)^{\frac{2(\epsilon +2 )}{k}}}  $

$\implies \frac{1}{b} > \frac{c_5}{a(ab)^{\frac{2(\epsilon +2 )}{k}}}  $ [ using inequality (c)]

$\implies a(a^2b^2)^{\frac{2.1}{k}} >bc_5 $  [$\epsilon =0.1$]

$\implies a(a^2b^2)^{\frac{2.1}{k}} >b \implies b \ll_k a(a^2b^2)^{\frac{2.1}{k}} $